# To size your (u)ints or not?

Tags: c, coding-style, embedded

I googled for this, and was surprised to find no guidelines, rules of thumb, styles, etc. When declaring a (signed or not signed) integer in C, one can make the choice to just use whatever the processor defines for int, or one can specify the width (e.g. `uint16_t`, `int8_t`, `uint32_t`, etc).

When doing desktop/dedicated C programs, I've tended very much towards the "just use the defaults" unless it was really important for me to specify width (e.g. "this is a 32 bit ID").

Having done more microcontroller work lately (pic18 and AVR), I've tended to size everything, just because you become so space conscience.

And now I'm working on some Pic32 code (no OS), where I find myself torn between the two extremes.

I'm curious what rubric (if any) people have formulated that help them decide when to size their ints, and when to use the defaults? And why?

Comment: When writing non-throwaway software, I tend to use the `uint_least32_t` etc. types unless I need a specific size. That lets me be sure about a minimum size, and allows the compiler optimise for the next larger size it's good at.

Comment: This question is soliciting an opinion. Usually, I reserve the sized integers for data types that are being communicated across a network or being stored on a disk and may be read by a different program later.

Comment: @jxh I follow the same practice. If it's a data type that's only for internal consumption of a standalone instance (i.e., not distributed) of the process which defines the data type, I let the compiler choose its opinion of the "best size" for the type. For anything which leaves the process (either for persistent storage or for inter-process communication), I'd rather be explicit in the data sizing. You may still have to be aware of endianness problems, but at least the data size is predictable.

Comment: If portability is at all a concern, use `[u]int_leastN_t` and `[u]int_fastN_t` types or built-in types (they are almost the same). `[u]intN_t` types are optional.

Comment: I've got the feeling that worrying too much about sizing ints in most cases causes much more brain damage than you have advantages (size, performance etc.) Of course there are always exceptions where every little bit you can squeeze out of your code counts.

Answer (score 6):

If something is important to you, try to make it as explicit as possible.
If you don't really care, let the compiler decide.

This is quite close to what you wrote yourself. If you must follow a specification, that says something is 32bit, use a sized type. If it's just a loop counter, use `int`.

Answer (score 2):

There actually is a guideline that mentions this. [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) has a rule that says you should always use sized types. But the rule is only advisory, not required or mandatory for compliance.

From [here](http://www.ristancase.com/html/dac/manual/3.12.02%20MISRA-C%202004%20Rules.html):

> 6.3 (adv): 'typedefs' that indicate size and signedness should be used in place of the basic types.

Answer (score 2):

You should use both.

The Misra rule is good, but doesn't fit everywhere.

To use sized types is better for crossplatform compiling, like simulation of an embedded software at a pc platform.

But even then you need to regards `printf` sizes against sized types.

```
uint32_t val;

printf("%d", val);
printf("%ld", (long)val);
```

The first `printf` works on many 32bit platform, but fails on many embedded platforms with int=16bit/long=32bit.

```
uint16_t len = strlen("text");
```

Can produce warnings, as the return type of strlen is `int` and `int` can be larger than `uint16_t`, here it's better to use `int len`.